# How to setup login to youtube with data api using JS

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-channels

I can't find any documentation on youtube developers page for creating a form on login to youtube account or google.

It's okay if there is an embed frame for that login. I just need a guide, I'll do the coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#authorizing_requests

It gives you the code for 4 files (Each of which would be needed) that creates an HTML form which, when a user clicks a button, offers the oAuth2 authorization page ... and, once that is clicked on, redirects back to the app but hides the login button in favor of a little upload widget. It should help you see the general flow, and then you can tailor it to your own needs.